# jquery selector to select parent's first hidden element with an id that contains "AID"

Tags: jquery

I want to select the parents first hidden element with an id value that contains "AID". How do I do that ?

My code so far:

```
function appendControl(e) { 
    var AnsID = $("input:hidden[value='1']"); 
    alert(AnsID.val()); 
    var parent = $(e).parent().get(0); 
    var answerbox = $(e).prev("div"); 
    $(answerbox).append("<div class='ansitem'>Hello World here I am this is me !</div>"); 
}
```

->div.
---input(target)
---some div
---span
---a (control)

**EDIT**
GUYS can you flag this for deletion pls.

Assuming I don't know the  full ID or class of the target , I want to be able to select the ID of the target containing "AID". The target is the first child of the current element's parent.

Comment: What have you tried? What else do you need to know beyond that what http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ or http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ describe?

Comment: function appendControl(e) {
                var AnsID = $("input:hidden[value='1']");
                alert(AnsID.val());
                var parent = $(e).parent().get(0);
                var answerbox = $(e).prev("div");
                $(answerbox).append("<div class='ansitem'>Hello World here I am this is me !</div>");
            }

Comment: Code in comments is always highly unreadable. I added it to your question (which you should do the next time as well). Still, this snippet is not helpful without knowing the HTML structure and what `e` is.

Comment: thanks Felix ! I will edit the question to reflect my html structure

Comment: You can post actual HTML, you just have to format your code properly. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

With not much of details, try adding some class and do:

```
$(this).parents(":someClass:hidden:first");
```

Hope its helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the documentation on jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

You probably want to look into [the `Attribute Contains` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
'[id*="AID"]'
```

...[the `:hidden` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

And [the `:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

Comment: the API is already open, but I couldn't find this (*= ) was for that. I was browsing http://api.jquery.com/browser/
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything? We love to help but this community is not a service that does your work.

This SHOULD work but please bear with me if it doesn't because lack of experience with these kind of selectors.

```
$('*:hidden:first[id*="AID"]').parent();
```

I do highly suggest to replace the first `*` with a more specific selector like an element, class or id.

Comment: thanks a lot for that , and I do not assume you are people to do my work. I knew basic selections but had no idea about filtering to the controls with IDS that "contain" AID. Thanks again

Comment: does the selector below work for selecting the previous elements first child which contains "AID" ?
$('*:hidden:first[id*="AID"]').prev();

Comment: I don't think so, because the `:first` selector selects the first element already, so it cant pick a previous element. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I have updated this question with a snap of the DOM tree. @Tim can you answer it for me pls.

here is the link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560270/select-first-hidden-input-element-of-the-previous-control-on-the-same-node/8560281#8560281