# select first hidden input element of the previous control on the same node

Tags: jquery

[image]

Above you can see my DOM , how do I get to the input from the a tag  as shown below. Note that the portion is repeated multiple times as it is derived from a repeater control.

I did post a similar question earlier , which I have flagged for deletion as the question seems to be confusing.

The target is a hidden field, and assume that I only know that the ID is suffixed with "AID". So how can i select it ?

here is what i have tried , but i know its wrong though

```
var AnsID = $('*:hidden:first[id*="AID"]').prev("div");
```

any help appreciated guys. thanks!

Comment: _"target the particular control from the target"_... that's a lot of targets ;-) So do you want to get the `<input>` from the `<a>` ? Could you simply post a piece of the HTML ?

Comment: yes , target the input from a...and i cant paste html as its too lengthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).prev('div').children('input[id*="AID"]:hidden:first');
```

Where `this` is the `a` tag.

As you can see, I select the previous `div` element, then I access the first hidden input child that contains `aid` in the `id` attribute.

This should work.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz because the method `child` is supposed to be `children`. My bad... Should work now!

Comment: I changed it to children and checked, not working still :/ am all blanks here !

also it doesn't look like you are looking for the previous div on the same node as the current element

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz `.prev()` works on the same node level as the current element, which is in your case the `a` tag. I see you're experiencing trouble both with mine solution as the one Samrich posted while they are both working on the jsfiddle Samrich supplied. So either you gave wrong information or you're doing something wrong. Are you sure you're using the snippet in a `click` handler on applied to the `a` tag? If not, the `this` syntax won't work.

Comment: Yes Tim , I am starting to think same too. Will recheck those areas and update you on that. Thanks for your time @Tim.

Comment: Tim , It seems I have got the suffix as "AnsID" and not "AID" . Little things create so much problems ! thanks tim

Answer (score 2):

```
var v = $(this).prev().find('input[id$="AID"]:hidden:eq(0)').val();
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/F2wDb/1/

Comment: I've added example in jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't see that your example is applicable in this context. Can you explain how this example fits in to this context ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i missed suffix.. I've updated sample. In this sample clicking on each `a` will find input and show result for you.

Comment: Have you checked example: http://jsfiddle.net/F2wDb/1/. Is this html like in your scenario?

Comment: @Samich. Update your answer with the code from the fiddle, they don't match.

Comment: My scenario is having an a on the same node as the parent of the input.

Comment: So, in jsfiddle it has `a` on the same level as `div` containig target element, doesn't it?

Comment: I will post the html and edit the question . take a look at that Samich ..thanks

Comment: @Samich the html is too lengthy so i cannot post it here.. :(

Comment: Post it to jsfiddle and post link here